# Plotting High Pass Transfer Function in Matlab

Tags: transfer-function, matlab, high-pass-filter

I've been trying to practice using Matlab for circuit analysis and am trying to create a transfer function plot of a high pass filter where the gain is in volts/volts not in dB.

This is the information I am given:

- R = 10,
- C = 0.3e-3, 0.45e-3, and 1e-3
- w = 0.01:0.1:4000 rad/sec

I've been trying to use the bode() in Matlab returns a transfer function in dB and I was wondering how I could plot it with volts/volt unit and plot all four outputs for each capacitor on the same plot.

Comment: Hmm... a bode plot is _supposed_ to plot a dB magnitude plot because that's what a bode plot represents... The only thing I can think of is if you plot your transfer function on an X-Y Axis instead of plotting bode graph.

Comment: The bode plot shows you logarithmic behavior, that's why you see dB, because as you know, to convert V/V to dB you have to convert it to 20log(V/V).